# Which UUID does iOS use as a key to cache the characteristics table of a BLE device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Does anyone know which UUID (or other BLE info) iOS is using as the key to cache the characteristics table of a BLE device ?

ie: what id should be changed in a ble device firmware to make iOS refresh its cache or recreate a new cache entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bluetooth device address.

Note that per Bluetooth specification, a client is only allowed to cache the GATT table for bonded devices or devices that don't have the Service Changed characteristic in the GATT Service.

Comment: Yes i've seen that. Ty.

Comment: Unfortunatly the BT device address is the BT MAC address and can not be changed between firmware udpates. There must be another key.